# NodeJs splicing object from array correctly but not deleting the correct object in the DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Trying to delete an object from an array list, after being `.splice()` then save it to DB. Though it's splicing the correct `index` but not saving it correctly, if I `splice` index `0`, its actually deleting index `1` in the DB, probably because of the object has been spliced first therefore it's saving the wrong object.

```
var user = 
  {
   "requests" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Test1",
        "id" : "590e6c94b2d6e52674992d16",
        "email" : "kram@kram.com",
        "user" : "test",
        "accepted" : false
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Test2",
        "id" : "590e6c8bb2d6e52674992d15",
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "user" : "_test",
        "accepted" : false
    }
]
  }
```

accepOrdeny object example if user `test1` sent a request to the `xUser` -

```
{
    "name" : "Test1",
    "id" : "590e6c94b2d6e52674992d16",
    "email" : "kram@kram.com",
    "user" : "test",
    "accepted" : false
}
```

if the request has been accepted, `accepted` property `boolean` will switch to `true` and if denied then `accepted: false`.

```
{
    "name" : "Test1",
    "id" : "590e6c94b2d6e52674992d16",
    "email" : "kram@kram.com",
    "user" : "test",
    "accepted" : true
}
```

Splicing it and saving

```
let xd = user.requests.indexOf(acceptOrdeny);
user.requests.splice(xd, 1);
user.save(callback);
```

full code logic --

```
 User.findOne({ _id: currUser._id }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        /* acceptOrdeny is the req.body object
         checking if the key accepted==true then push acceptOrdeny object to friends[], splice from request[] then save to DB 
        */
        if (acceptOrdeny.accepted == true) {

            user.friends.push(acceptOrdeny);
            let indexReq = user.requests.indexOf(acceptOrdeny);
            user.requests.splice(indexReq, 1);
            user.save(callback);
            console.log('accepted', indexReq)
        }
        /* 
         checking if the key accepted==false remove from requests[], then save current array[] list
        */
        else {
            let xd = user.requests.indexOf(acceptOrdeny);
            user.requests.splice(xd, 1);
            user.save(callback);
        }
    });
```

I have tested `splice` the object manual like, this is fine but splicing them dynamically using `indexOf` is not quite right.

```
user.requests.splice(0, 1); // delete first obj in the array 'test1'
user.requests.splice(1, 1); // delete 2nd obj in the array 'test2'
```

Is there a better way of deleting the object in the obj[] list then save it back to the DB?

**EDIT**
output object, its doing the filter just fine but not deleting from the `requestsp[]`.

```
    Request { user_added: '5910a77a0f03b33dbc482bfe',
  name: 'Mark',
  username: '_markie',
  email: 'mark@mark.com',
  req_sent_by: 'Mark',
  accepted: false }

accept/deny obj { user_added: '5910a77a0f03b33dbc482bfe',
  name: 'Mark',
  username: '_markie',
  email: 'mark@mark.com',
  req_sent_by: 'Mark',
  accepted: true }
```

Comment: Is acceptOrdeny a reference to the same exact object that you're looking for via indexOf?

Comment: yes, if I just console.log(acceptOrdeny) it gives me the right objects that I want to delete.

Comment: I see `user.request` is defined, but you're referring to `user.requests`. Is that just a typo in the example?

Comment: @Caleb, if you meant the var `request` then yeah that was just a typo in the example. It's actually `requests`, if you see the full logic it defines it correctly.

Comment: `requests` embedded doc in `user` only has fields `name` and `url` while `acceptOrdeny` also has `accepted ` So `let indexReq = user.requests.indexOf(acceptOrdeny)` will always be `-1`. So `user.requests.splice(-1, 1)` will always remove the last element.

Comment: I've updated my json example, and yes it's returning `-1`. Is it possible to correct the code, if you think its wrong?

Comment: Take the back, even in the `true` condition it doesn't remove the correct obj in the DB. :(

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is happening is that indexOf is not finding the correct item, and is instead returning -1.

indexOf uses the equals operator and there might be a conflict between the mongoose retrieval and express body object, resulting in something like this:

```
var toFind = {'a': 1}
var arr = [{'a': 1}, {'b':2}]
var idx = arr.indexOf(toFind)
//here, idx = -1, but you think idx = 0
```

You need to implement your own comparator and use filter

```
user.requests = user.requests.filter(request => !(request.id.equals(acceptOrdeny.id)))
```

Same thing, but more verbose:

```
user.requests = user.requests.filter(function(request){
    return !(request.id.equals(acceptOrdeny.id))
}
```

You might need to call id.toString() on one or both of the strings, depending on your data format.

Also, you are using duplicate logic, and could simplify by doing:

```
 User.findOne({ _id: currUser._id }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    /* acceptOrdeny is the req.body object
     checking if the key accepted==true then push acceptOrdeny object to friends[], splice from request[] then save to DB 
    */

    if (acceptOrdeny.accepted == true) {
        user.friends.push(acceptOrdeny);
    }

    /* 
     checking if the key accepted==false remove from requests[], then save current array[] list
    */
    user.requests = user.requests.filter(request => !(request.id.equals(acceptOrdeny.id)));
    user.save(callback);
});
```

Comment: Indeed its quite strange, though the `true` condition is working fine, its deleting the correct object in the DB. Tried yours and it didn't work, didn't even splice anything.

Comment: @MrNew woops, I was using splice but mean slice. Edited

Comment: :) that duplicated the object I'm trying to delete.

Comment: It certainly shouldn't have. The acceptOrDeny.accepted == true condition works properly? Something weird is definitely going on. Try moving the request logic out of the if/else statement, because you do it regardless

Comment: @Mrnew, I think I found your problem, and edited my answer. indexOf is probably returning -1

Comment: The objects might have the same values, but indexOf does a strict comparison meaning the two objects must reference the same object in memory. Look up javascript strict comparison if this is still confusing.

Comment: sorry for such a late reply to your comment, though I'm getting `equals` is not a function. `request.id.equals is not a function`

Comment: Instead I use this `.filter(request => request.id == acceptOrdeny.id` but its not deleting the object from the `requests` array.

Comment: can you do a console.log(request) and console.log(acceptOrDeny). One id is probably a string and one id is probably an ObjectId

Comment: Ids are both strings, so its kinda strange. I's pushing the right object but not deleting.

Comment: I've added the console.log() output of both in my question.

Comment: As you can see, neither the request or acceptOrdeny has an "id" field. I don't know which field you're using to identify unique requests, but I suspect that you want to use request.user_added === acceptOrdeny.user_added

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake, I changed it before pasting it here it's `user_added`, its the right object but not deleting which is my current issue at the moment. `filter(request => request.user_added == acceptOrdeny.user_added)`

Comment: filter(request => !(request.user_added == acceptOrdeny.user_added))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143735/discussion-between-mrnew-and-aidan-hoolachan).